# Setting component state, but this.props.state is undefined in render() method

Tags: reactjs

I'm making a get request  within my component's componentDidMount() method. I'm able to successfully make the request and set my component's state. However, when I try to get access to state within my render() method, it comes back as undefined. I'm guessing it has something to do with the asynchronous nature of javascript, but can't seem to figure out how to properly set the state, wait to make sure that state has been set, then pass it down to my render() method so I can access it there. Thanks.

**Game.js (component file)**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Game extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }

  getReviews() {
    const _this = this;
    axios.get('/api/reviews')
      .then(function(response) {
        _this.setState({
          data: response.data
        });
        console.log(_this.state.data); // shows that this is an array of objects.
      })
      .catch(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getReviews();
  }


  render() {

    const allReviews = this.props.data.map((review) => {
       return (
         <li>{review.username}</li>
       );
    })

    console.log(this.props.data); // comes in as undefined here.

    return (
      <div>
        {allReviews}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't you mean `this.state.data` not `this.props.data`?

Comment: Yes! Thanks so much, not sure how I missed that. Appreciate it.